# How to use minimized version of Ol3 library

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, openlayers-3

I have a problem using the minimized version of OL3 library. It doesn't include the goog namespace. I do not know if it is not included in the js file or is the 'goog' namespace obfuscated.

But this part can be easily handled by just including Google closure library in a separate file. But after I do that I get another two errors:

1. **NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/my_test_app/apps/deps.js**: should I include this file as well and if yes, should I include all other files from google closure library which this file tries to add dependencies to ?
2. **ol.proj.Units is undefined**: this one looks like obfuscated namespaces
   And again it also looks like some namespaces were changed.

Shouldn't the namespaces, just like public methods, be kept unchanged in the obfuscated file ?

I tried to use the latest version of OL3: 3.8.2

Comment: Did nobody ever use the minified version of OL3 library ??

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time, and it works fine...  I use debug for local testing and then build a production version with the minified library.  Did you build your own or are you using the ones from the OL server downloaded, or via a CDN link.

Comment: I use the files from the official OL3 distribution - I do not build it myself. Do you also implement your custom interactions ? I think that the problem resides in using the goog namespace as I described in the post. And did you try to use ol.proj.Units somewhere in your production code too?

Comment: Could be a build bug in the latest release?  I don't use goog outside of the library so I believe it's all in there for OL.

Comment: It is not only the latest release. I have had this problem since I started Using OL3. If goog is to be used by OL only, then how am I supposed to write my own interactions ? I can use other libraries to simulate inheritance in javascript but I cannot be sure if they will do everything right for OL classes.

Comment: I think the OL library is meant to be used 'as-is' unless there are explicit hooks to the internals that you can override - if you want to rewrite the internals yourself you are looking at a custom build from the github repository.

Comment: I do not want to rewrite the internals. I want to extend them. But well - it looks like I will need to find another way to do what I need. Thanks @pconnell99 for your help. I'll save some time now avoiding dead ends :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to load the goog namespace in production, there is a good discussion with good example of how to create an OpenLayers3 control with plain javascript on the OL3 GitHub. https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3943

ol.proj.Units is not obfuscated, it is part of the public library. It's value is probably not initialized correctly in your application.